# Receiving error on eecute reader that my sql syntax is incorrect

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, mysqlcommand

I am going to guess the issue is that I have two seperate queries inside one command. Is there a way to get around this?

The connection string is filled with example data but it connects correctly.

I'm also aware that it's not secure to put connection strings inside the actual file but this is for testing purposes at the moment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Multiple_forms
{
    public partial class Register : Form
    {
        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void registerSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myConnection = "Server=localhost;Database=Houses;Uid=user;Pwd=password;";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

            string selectQuery = "Select * from users where RegistrationKey = '" + this.regKeyTextBox.Text + ";" + "UPDATE users set UserName = '" + this.regUsernameTextBox.Text.ToLower() +
                                 "', Password = '" + this.regPasswordTextBox.Text + "', Email ='" +
                                 this.regEmailTextBox.Text + "' WHERE RegistrationKey = '" + this.regKeyTextBox.Text +
                                 "';";

            string inputPass = this.regPasswordTextBox.Text;
            string inputPassConfirm = this.regPasswordConfirmTextBox.Text;

            MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, myConn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            if (inputPass == inputPassConfirm)
            {
                myConn.Open();
                myReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();



            int regCount = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                regCount = regCount + 1;
            }

            if (regCount == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have registered successfully!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid registration key.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Passwords don't match.");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your query `selectQuery` contains an error. You don't close the quotation marks after `this.regKeyTextBox.Text `

Comment: First mistake, saving the actual password...

Comment: Second mistake: Using user input to build an sql statement without escaping input.

Comment: I'm aware of the second mistake it is a test for the moment but, what would be an alternative to the first mistake?

Comment: @O'Cheezy hashing and salting, never store passwords like that.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Ok, thank you! I'm sorry I'm sure that's something easy but I'm just starting.

Comment: @O'Cheezy no problem, you're welcome, we're always learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you receive an Sql Syntax Error, I suspect the problems lays in your query `selectQuery`. As you can see below, you do not close the quotation marks after `this.regKeyTextBox.Text`.

```
 string selectQuery = "Select * from users where RegistrationKey = '" + this.regKeyTextBox.Text + ";" + "UPDATE users set UserName = '" + this.regUsernameTextBox.Text.ToLower() +
                      "', Password = '" + this.regPasswordTextBox.Text + "', Email ='" +
                      this.regEmailTextBox.Text + "' WHERE RegistrationKey = '" + this.regKeyTextBox.Text +
                      "';";
```

Try changing the query to :

```
string selectQuery = "Select * from users where RegistrationKey = '" + this.regKeyTextBox.Text + "';" + "UPDATE users set UserName = '" + this.regUsernameTextBox.Text.ToLower() +
                      "', Password = '" + this.regPasswordTextBox.Text + "', Email ='" +
                      this.regEmailTextBox.Text + "' WHERE RegistrationKey = '" + this.regKeyTextBox.Text +
                      "';";
```

Comment: I feel stupid for a small syntax error but thank you!

Comment: Don't worry, this kind of things happen all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Update It like

```
string selectQuery = "Select * from users where RegistrationKey = '" + this.regKeyTextBox.Text + "';" + "UPDATE users set UserName = '" + this.regUsernameTextBox.Text.ToLower() +
                                 "', Password = '" + this.regPasswordTextBox.Text + "', Email ='" +
                                 this.regEmailTextBox.Text + "' WHERE RegistrationKey = '" + this.regKeyTextBox.Text +
                                 "';";
```